# ionic radio group ng-model select

Tags: angular, radio-group, ionic4

I'm trying to implement a ngModel on a ion-radio element for changing unit for my app . every is fine , but when select option one and select option tow he is stack on option one ! . l want make user to chose only only option

html :

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-radio-group>
      <ion-list-header>
        Unit Fuel
      </ion-list-header>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>LBS</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="LBS" [(ngModel)]="Fuel_lbs"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>KG</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="KG" [(ngModel)]="Fuel_kg"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
```

my operation code to do math operation for lbs and kg

```
    public Fuel_kg: boolean = false; 
      public Fuel_lbs: boolean = false; 

      public object: any;
      constructor(public http: HTTP,public https: HttpClient,public alertCtrl:AlertController) {

      }
 async addThemFunction () {

  if (this.Fuelunit_lbs ==true) {
    let  firstNumber = this.firstNumber ? parseFloat(this.firstNumber) : 0 ;
    let  mainfuellbs = this.mainfuellbs ? parseFloat(this.mainfuellbs) : 2200 ;
    if(firstNumber==0){
      let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: 'Alert',
        message: 'Pleas Enter value !',
          buttons: ['OK']
      });
      await alert.present();

  }else{
    this.totallbs =firstNumber * mainfuellbs;
    this.clickMessageforlbs='This flight is around '+ firstNumber + ' nm , so you need '

  }
  console.log("clicked!");

  }else if (this.Fuel_kg==true) {
    let  firstNumber = this.firstNumber ? parseFloat(this.firstNumber) : 0 ;
    let  mainfuelkg = this.mainfuelkg ? parseFloat(this.mainfuelkg) : 1000 ;
    if(firstNumber==0){
      let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: 'Alert',
        message: 'Pleas Enter value !',
          buttons: ['OK']
      });
      await alert.present();

  }else{
    this.totallbs =firstNumber * mainfuelkg;
    this.clickMessageforkg='This flight is around '+ firstNumber + ' nm , so you need '

  }
  console.log("clicked!");
  }

  }
```

with ngmodel l cant chose one select

[image]

with out ngmodel

[image]

[ionic doc radio group](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio)

any help please ?

Comment: Just use one varible as ngModel, and set it on `<ion-radio-group>` tag :) You can when you need, instead check which value your variable has, is it `LBS` or `KG`.

Comment: I have to use both ngmodel , for lbs and kg . If i but the ngmodel in '<ion-radio-group>' only the values don't switch!!!

Comment: There is way to put lbs and kg in one ngmodel ?

Comment: Well just like the duplicate suggest and as my comment says... https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-adh9pc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thank you for reply , l want use Boolean false and true for ngmodel . you can see in my code above i did to boolean for lbs and kg to do operation math . my point now is how to make boolean ngmodel for unit and through unit switch from lbs to kg. i dont know you if you get my point . thank you

Comment: check my code question update

Comment: Hmm... I don't see why you couldn't do `if unit === 'KG' { .. do stuff .. } else { ... }`?

Comment: @AJT_82 . oh my code . l didn't know about `if unit === 'KG' { .. do stuff .. } else { ... }` . anyway he is working now . thank you for help

Comment: No problem, glad we got it sorted out! :)